# Images not loading locally on React using Gatsby

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

I'm running into a weird issue where if I try to load an image locally, I get a compile error.

This is my compile error: [Compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZsx2.png)

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import * as React from 'react'
import test from '..\images\128PxNewAcluLogo2017Svg.png'

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <img src={test} alt="test" />
    </main>
)
}

export default IndexPage
```

Loading the image from an online source works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use counter slashes(`\`), use it like:

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import * as React from 'react'
import test from '../images/128PxNewAcluLogo2017Svg.png'

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <img src={test} alt="test" />
    </main>
)
}

export default IndexPage
```

Otherwise, it will be interpreted as escaping values.